# How to Add a Header to the XML Preamble i.e "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" in xml document?

Tags: c#, xml, syndication-feed

Here I wish to add a namespace to the forst line of xml document i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I am creating the xml file using c# with the help of syndicate rss feed.
it should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" xmlns:example="www.example.com ?>
```

Comment: The namespace should be added to the root tag and not the identification line.

Comment: another good post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601759/c-sharp-add-xml-namespace-xmlns-tag-to-document

Comment: That line is called the XML Preamble.

Comment: Hello will,the question is different i think because i have a different scenario

Comment: @Ma6139735 The solution to the marked question answers this one.  The different "scenario" is irrelevant.

Comment: but why you were in so hurry?to mark it as a duplicate question, you could suggest to update it?don't you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `xmlns` attribute to add the namespace like

```
doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "www.example.com");
```